# Unity video player - play a default video until another video is completly loaded

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-streaming, video-player

I have a video player in Unity that loads a video from a server.
The loading time of the video can be long, so I decided to display a "loading" video while I load the video from the server.

I have tried to add another video player component to another object, but rendering two videos on the same texture is problematic.

Is there a way to display a default video while the real video is being loaded by the video player component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact same problem.
I kind of solved it by using two video players as you said, but I also switched the textured of the video players.
The video player of the loading video is rendering to textureA which is the texture where I play the video, and the other one render to an unused texture.
When the real video finish to load I switch the video player's textures.

This solution is working but it isn't efficient, and I am still looking for an efficient solution.

Comment: Thanks! Let me know if you find something.